# How do I make a UDP client where I can send and receive the messages at the same time? (in C)

Tags: c, linux, sockets, udp, client-server

I have a simple UDP client/server program where the server just echos the message sent by the client. The problem is when I try to send multiple messages. I do something like

```
    for (i = 0; i < number_of_messages; i++) {
        sendto(...);
        recvfrom(...);
    }
```

I want my client to consider the message dropped if it takes more than 5 seconds, but I want the whole program to take around 5 seconds too. For instance, I don't want it to wait 5 seconds for each message, I just want the whole program to wait 5 seconds and constantly send and receive messages in that time period until it hits number_of_messages or the 5 second time constraint.

Right now, the client is doing a send, receive, send, receive, etc. type of program. Is there a way to send and receive simultaneously? I think there is a simple solution using multiple constraints in the for loop but I just can't figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: Check out `select(2)`.

Comment: My friend says there's a way to do this without select or threads. I want it do it that way because it seems simple. I really do think it's just something really obvious that I'm missing

Comment: Your friend is mistaken. If he disagrees let him answer the question. Or possibly he is thinking of `poll()` or `epoll().` Or of non-blocking I/O without select/poll/epoll, which is a mistake.

Comment: Yeah I'm stopping blocking recvfrom() by using setsockopt(). Why is that a mistake?

Comment: I didn't say it was a mistake. I said 'non-blocking mode *without select/poll/epoll*' [emphasis added] is a mistake. If you want simultaneity you will have to use a thread, by definition. Or else your fried is thinking of asynchronous mode. I don't know why you're asking us when you should be asking him.

Comment: What is asynchronous mode? Can I interweave sending and receiving with that?